# How To Generate A Random Decimal Value In Mysql

Tags: mysql

I am trying to generate a random value between 0.01 - 0.50 to enter into mysql. I have 2.7 million rows that I need to execute this on.

Here is my script:

```
 UPDATE FBAInventory SET buyBox = ROUND( 0.01 + RAND( ) * 8,2 );
```

It is generating values such as 4.20, 3.89 etc. I only want it to span from 0.01 - 0.50 and not to exceed this.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

How about...

```
round(rand() * 0.49 + 0.01, 2);
```

Comment: This works perfectly, though I had to add a 0 to the front of .49.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the floor function to generate a range of random numbers.

```
FLOOR(RAND() * (<max> - <min> + 1)) + <min>
```

where the max and min are inclusive. So in your case you would want

```
FLOOR(RAND() * 1.49 ) + 0.01
```